# Dehash Bcrypt hashSync

Tags: javascript, bcrypt

So lets say I have this

```
var hashedApi = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.api_token, 8);
```

Then I want to be able to later dehash the API token and use it later to verify a user. How would I go about dehashing the API token to use later? Thank you

Comment: What bcrypt library are you using? If https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt, it doesn't have a facility to dehash things.

Comment: hashes are not reversible.